# Enforcing qcut to split into equiprobable groups

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2])
pd.qcut(s, 2, labels=False)
```

I would like to get equiprobable groups, that is `[0, 0, 1, 1]`. Instead, `qcut` can either raise an exception or return `[0, 0, 0, 0]` (depending on the duplicates kwarg).

I got the equiprobable groups by disturbing slightly the data, that is:

```
def my_qcut(s, *args, **kwargs):
    disturbed = np.array(s) + np.random.rand(len(s)) / 1000
    return pd.qcut(disturbed, *args, **kwargs)
```

Although it seems to work, I feel that this is too hacky. Can anyone advise me on the deterministic way of splitting into equiprobable groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.qcut(s.rank(method='first'), 2, labels=np.arange(2))
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

### Using Numpy's `argsort` to rank

```
def qcut(s, n):
  k = len(s)
  a = s.values.argsort()
  b = np.empty_like(a)
  b[a] = np.arange(k) * n // k
  return pd.Series(b, s.index)

qcut(s, 2)

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```